# I am getting error while integrating tomcat with Eclipse Ide

Tags: eclipse, tomcat9, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to integrate Tomcat ver9.0 server with eclipse oxygen Ide but I am getting following Error
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Tomcat 9.0 Eclipse Oxygen

It should get integrated with my Eclipse Ide

Answer (score 0):

This is [fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162) in the current release. Update.